# fatal error: Index out of range without using any array

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

fatal error: Index out of range withot using any array when i convert date into week day using loop

```
 func getDayOfWeek(_ today:String) -> String? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from:today)
        let weekDay = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from:date!)]
        return weekDay
    }
```

Comment: show the date string you use with this code

Comment: 2017-03-20T04:13:00Z

Comment: show the code of loop

Comment: It only doesnt work if its sunday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from:date!)` start from 1 to 7, but index of the `weekdaySymbols` only from 0 to 6, so you have to minus one to get the correct weekday:

```
let weekDay = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from:date!)-1]
```

Also should be using `if let` and optional like the other answer suggest, to avoid crashing

Answer (score 0):

This is an array:

`dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols`

Also 'date' could be nil if the string was wrong format. You should check like this:

```
func getDayOfWeek(_ today:String) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:today) {
        let weekDay = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from:date)]
        return weekDay
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert week day to week index!

```
let weekname = getWeekDayName(weekDay: calendar.component(.weekday, from: date()))

func getWeekDayName(weekDay:Int) -> String
{
    let f = DateFormatter()
    let index:Int = (weekDay - 1) % 7
    print("Week No: " + String(weekNo) + " No: " + String(index))
    let weekName = f.weekdaySymbols[index]
    print("Week Name: " + weekName)
    return weekName
}
```